# Custom segue in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, segue

I am trying to make a custom seque where src falls down revealing dst. This is what I currently have. How can I make dst be behind src?

```
-(void)perform {
    UIViewController *src = [self sourceViewController];
    UIViewController *dst = [self destinationViewController];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                          delay:0.0
                        options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn
                     animations:^{
                         [src.parentViewController.view setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, src.view.bounds.size.height)];
                     }
                     completion:nil];

    [src presentViewController:dst animated:NO completion:nil];

}
```

Comment: iOS 7 is still under NDA. So in current format it's offtopic. You need to contact developer.apple for the support

Comment: Question is exactly the same in the context of iOS 6. Will change the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than arranging your destination view controller be behind your source controller, why not try this instead: render your source view controller to an image view, add that image to your source controller, and then animate the image falling down.

This has a number of benefits: firstly, whatever you end up doing you may need to render your source view controller out to an image *anyway* for performance reasons. Secondly, it avoids having to mess around with the view controller hierarchy.

If that wasn't totally clear, here it is step by step:

1. Render your source view controller out to a `UIImageView`
2. Add that `UIImageView` to your destination view controller (so that it covers the destination view entirely)
3. Remove your source view controller and add the destination controller - this should be seamless/invisible, since your destination controller is showing the rendered image you prepared earlier.
4. Animate the `UIImageView` falling down to reveal the view content beneath it